# FSCalendar date pop ups up full subtitle when selcted

Tags: swift

[![image of current calendar tab][1]][1]

I am using FSCalendar in Xcode to create multiple events. I have made it as far as having specific events with dots and a subtitle. I am trying to get the full description in this case the subtitle pop up somewhere so it can be fully read. I don't know where to begin other than FSCalendar's select function. Right now I just have an event for October 3rd as a test that says "Hello today us house four". As you can see its too big for the squares to read all of it.

```
import UIKit
import FSCalendar
class CalendarController: UIViewController {

    fileprivate weak var calendar: FSCalendar!    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let calendar = FSCalendar(frame: CGRect(x: 8, y: 200, width: 350, height: 420))
        calendar.dataSource = self
        calendar.delegate = self
        view.addSubview(calendar)
        self.calendar = calendar
    }

    var datesWithEvent = ["2019-10-03", "2015-10-06", "2015-10-12", "2015-10-25"]
    var datesWithMultipleEvents = ["2015-10-08", "2015-10-16", "2015-10-20", "2015-10-28"]

    fileprivate lazy var dateFormatter2: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        return formatter
    }()

    func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, numberOfEventsFor date: Date) -> Int {
        let dateString = self.dateFormatter2.string(from: date)
        if self.datesWithEvent.contains(dateString) {
            return 1
        }
        if self.datesWithMultipleEvents.contains(dateString) {
            return 3
        }
        return 0
    }

}
extension CalendarController: FSCalendarDataSource, FSCalendarDelegate{

        func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, subtitleFor date: Date) -> String? {
            let dateString = self.dateFormatter2.string(from: date)
            if self.datesWithEvent.contains(dateString) {

            return "Hello today is house four"
            }

        return nil
        }
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2zvg.png
```

Answer (score 0):

`FSCalendarDelegate` has `didSelect date` method just implement it.

```
func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar?, didSelect date: Date?, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) {
    if let date = date {
        let dateString = self.dateFormatter2.string(from: date)
        if self.datesWithEvent.contains(dateString) {
            print("House hours..") // you can show alert or show view
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't need to return 'string' in `subtitleFor ` method @scarface50377